# Как активировать кнопку при выборе двух элементов ListView? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть ListView и кнопка для сравнения двух элементов, которая должна быть активна, когда выбраны два элемента.
Есть такой код 
**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding CompareSnapshots}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=SnapshotsListView}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=SnapshotsListView, Converter={StaticResource selectedItemCollectionToBoolConverter}}"
    Content="Compare"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Margin="0,10,0,0"
    Width="130"
    Height="60"
    Grid.Column="1"/>
```

**Converter:**

```
class SelectedItemCollectionToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (((IList<object>)value).Count == 2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что биндинг отрабатывает только при запуске приложения. Как исправить?

Comment: `SelectedItems` — свойство только для чтение и его значение никогда не меняется, там ссылка всегда на одну и ту же коллекцию, меняется только ее содержимое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding CompareSnapshots}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=SnapshotsListView}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=SnapshotsListView, Converter={StaticResource selectedItemCollectionToBoolConverter}}"
    Content="Compare"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Margin="0,10,0,0"
    Width="130"
    Height="60"
    Grid.Column="1"/>
```

**Converter:**

```
class SelectedItemCollectionToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value == 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага, `SelectedItems` — наследник `ObservableCollection`, поэтому это работает. Круто.